# primefaces checkbox not binding

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Hi I´m doing an upolading images system , the upload method is fine but I have a simple checkbox in but when I wanna retrive the value, never was binded.

My JSF

```
    <h:body>

<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="2">

        <p:panel id="panel" header="Local import">

            <p:fileUpload style="padding:10px"
                fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadView.handleFileUpload}"
                mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false" multiple="true"
                update="messages" sizeLimit="900000" fileLimit="100"
                allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />

            <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />

            <p:outputLabel for="category" value="Category" />
            <p:inputText id="category" value="#{fileUploadView.path}"
                required="true" label="Path">
                <f:validateLength minimum="1" />
                <p:ajax update="msgCategory" event="keyup" />
            </p:inputText>
            <p:message for="category" id="msgCategory" display="icon" />

            <p:outputLabel for="document" value="Is a single document." />
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox style="padding:10px"
                value="#{fileUpload.singleDocument}" id="document" />
        </p:panel>


    </h:panelGrid>

</h:form>
```

This is the managed bean, is setted in  session scoope.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent;

@ManagedBean

public class FileUpload {

private String path = null;
private Boolean singleDocument;

public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile()
            .getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    try {
        copyFile(event.getFile().getFileName(), event.getFile()
                .getInputstream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void copyFile(String fileName, InputStream in) {
    try {

        // write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(path + fileName));
        System.out.println(path + fileName);
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }

        in.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        System.out.println("New file created!");
        System.out.println(singleDocument);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

// Getters and setters

public String getPath() {
    return path;
}

public void setPath(String path) {
    this.path = path;
}

public Boolean getSingleDocument() {
    return singleDocument;
}

public void setSingleDocument(Boolean singleDocument) {
    this.singleDocument = singleDocument;
}
```

}

Thanks in advance for your time and answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact the variable is never initialized. Either change `private Boolean singleDocument;` to `private boolean singleDocument`, or give the variable a value somewhere (zero args constructor or `@PostConstruct` annotated method or change it to `private Boolean singleDocument = Boolean.FALSE;`)...

Comment: I changed to private boolean singleDocument, and updated getters and setters form Boolean to boolean, and I´m getting false always.

Comment: Can you add a `p:ajax` on your `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` to make sure the setters are getting called?

Comment: i wrote  System.out.println("setted"); and  System.out.println("getted"); inside each metod. 
And nothing is printed

Comment: With `<p:ajax event="change" partialSubmit="true"/>` you ensure your component is submitted on change... Can you try that?

Comment: Oh, by the way, when you upload a file, is your `p:growl` shown?

Comment: Shouldn't it say "Succesful", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded."? ---  What happened with `p:ajax`?

Comment: yes you are rigth ajax returns that i get confused with the output console

Comment: And was the boolean value passed?

Comment: in the upload method  the value is passed but no in the checkbox.

Comment: I found the problem you was rigth all the time, in a getter method I keept Boolean, when i changed to boolean works perfect

Comment: Good to know, I was running out of options... Good luck Juan Camilo